# How do you calculate the force between an electromagnet and a piece of iron?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, electrical-engineering

I am building a simple electromagnet, with an Iron core, and want to calculate the force it can exert on another piece of Iron when in direct contact with it (Basically how much weight it can lift). Here are the parameters of my electromagnet:

Coil Turns = $200$ 
Length = $0.01$ (m) 
Cross-sectional Area = $0.000314$ ($m^2$, $r = 0.01$ m) 
Current = $1.79$ (amps, $V = 12, R = 6.7$) 
Core's magnetic permeability = $6.3 * 10^{-3}$ (Iron)

I have a cylindrical iron core with a radius of 1 and height of 1 (cm) and am wrapping 200 turns of 0.2 mm thick copper wire around it. I plan on lifting a block of Iron with it, that is the maximum weight possible. The design is supposed to look like a  miniature lifting electromagnet crane, similar to this:
[image]

The red lines show the coil wiring layout.

How can I calculate the force between the electromagnet and the block of iron?

Comment: The units for length should almost certainly be meters, not millimeters.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I tried with meters as well and got the same results. Edited the question

Comment: Beyond that, the formula given in that article is taken from the [Wikipedia article on electromagnets,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet) which makes some assumptions about the geometry that may or may not be true in your case.

Comment: Something seems off about that formula, it calculates the force on *what* object? And, at what distance is said object? Usually forces of field like that fall inversely as some function of the distance

Comment: @MahanLamee You could probably get an answer to your question if you phrase it more as "how do you calculate the force between an electromagnet and a piece of iron." It's not a simple answer and not generally covered in undergrad E+M. As others have noted, it doesn't look like you're using formulas that apply to your situation _at all_. I don't think this is a homework question at all... but the title _sounds like_ the title of an undergraduate electrodynamics homework question. Then people click on the link and see simple E+M equations, so they vote to close without reading the question.

Comment: @AXensen Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the title. I still don't know why the question is closed since it's not homework-like, but let's see if it ever gets reopened.

Comment: @MahanLamee It would be likely to be reopened if you removed the equations for $F$ and instead spent more time describing the geometry of your electromagnet and the geometry of the thing it's picking up. The second equation you have now has a symbol $g$ which is totally undefined... so that alone might get you closed for "not enough details or clarity." Especially if you made a simple drawing in microsoft paint or something. I for one will vote to reopen now.

Comment: Your top formula is to be found in the *Wiki* article on the electromagnet. It gives, I believe, the force needed to remove a detachable section of a closed-loop ferromagnetic core from the rest of the core (the part of the core with the coil wound round it). [By 'detachable' I mean needing almost no force to remove if there is no current in the coil and no residual magnetism in the core.]

Comment: @AXensen Okay, I am designing something up in CAD, in the mean time I updated the question with some textual descriptions

Comment: @PhilipWood Oh I see. Then that formula doesn't even remotely apply.

Comment: There is no red line that I can see…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sorry, fixed

Comment: @ Mahan Lamee Well, that was my reading of the *Wiki* article. See what you think. I don't see why the formula "doesn't remotely apply" to your case, if your electromagnet is U-shaped and the iron to be lifted spans the gap between the poles of the U. You would then have a closed loop. I note that the formula is correct as regards units, assuming that $\mu=\mu_0\mu_R$ in which $\mu_r$ is the relative permeability of the 'iron'. Unfortunately the latter quantity is hard to pin down, and isn't really a constant.

Comment: @PhilipWood Yes I saw the image on Wikipedia. My electromagnet is not U-shaped, but even then, trying to calculate the force for a hypothetical U-shaped version also gives a ridiculously large (~1 million newtons) amount of force for some reason.

Comment: @Mahan Lamee  I put $\mu_0=4\pi\times 10^{-7}$N A$^{-2}, \mu_R=100 \sqrt {10},\  N=100 \sqrt {10},\ I=1.0\ \text A, A=1.0\times 10^{-3} \text m^2, L=0.3$ m. The force came to about 140 N.

Comment: Sorry, 70 N....

Comment: @PhilipWood, Yes, that's right, but I put $\mu_R = 5000, N = 200, I = 1.79, A = 314\times 10^{-6},  L = 0.01$ which is my build parameters, and the force became $6321433$ newtons... So like either the relative permeability of iron is not 5000, or my length/area produces weird results.

Comment: Maybe you can build it first and actually measure the force, so you'll actually have some reference data to know whether any formula you use is correct (then you'll also have the details of the object the electromagnet acts on).

Comment: @Mahan Lamee. Yes, with your figures I, too, get a huge force. I think that 5000 may be too large for $\mu_r$, but, as I've said, it's very difficult to find  values for it. A centimetre is much too small, surely, for the length of the magnetic circuit, but multiplying it by 10 will only bring the force down by a factor of 100. Time for some experimental work, I think!